# Why did Magneto bring the subway train near Jean?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-dark-phoenix

In *Dark Phoenix* (2019), using his powers, Magneto brought the subway train to the surface near Jean:

[image: Magneto in front of a subway train]

Why did Magneto bring the subway train near Jean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's using it to block the main entrance, forcing his opponents to go around it (and the various human shields he now has behind him).

[image: Magneto in front of the subway]